# C Programming: Removing Unnecessary Commas From Result of Prefix Sum Code

Tags: c

I recently made code in C that reads a set of numbers until zero (zero ends the number set) and prints its prefix sum:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int x, sum;
    sum = 0;
    while(x)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        sum += x;
        if(x != 0)
        {
            printf("%d,", sum);    
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I were to type `2 3 5 7 11 0`: It would print the following:

```
2,5,10,17,28,
```

I was wondering how to remove the comma by the number `28` or to add commas to numbers until the last number?

Comment: Note that in general, you can't "remove" commas once you've written them.  The key is not to write the comma unless you want it.  The answers below all do that, one way or another.  Techniques such as seeking backwards a character and overwriting with a blank or newline work on files but not on pipes or terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred solution, adapted to the code in the question, is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int x;
    const char *pad = "";   /* Or put a prefix here */
    while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1 && x != 0)
    {
        sum += x;
        printf("%s%d", pad, sum);
        pad = ",";          /* Or use ", " if you prefer */
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code does not test the uninitialized variable `x` on the first iteration (unlike the code in the question), and it checks that the `scanf()` succeeds before using the value (unlike the code in the question).  These are routine precautions you should be taking.  It would be possible to adapt the code to keep track of how many bytes have been printed on the line (what's the return value from `printf()`?) and arrange for `pad` to contain `"\n"` (instead of a comma, or `",\n"` if you want a comma at the end of all lines except the last) when the line gets 'too long'.

Note too that if you type the numbers at the program, the output gets messy.  If the program is reading from a built-in list of numbers, or reading from a file, then you get good outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = -1;
    int ret;

    while(1)
    {
        i++;
        ret = scanf("%d", &x);

        if(ret != 1)
          break;

        sum += x;

        if(x != 0)
        {
            if(i == 0) 
               printf("%d", sum);
            else
              printf(",%d", sum);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
0
1,3,6
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the comma before all but the first value. It's not elegant but it works.

```
if(x != 0)
{
    if(sum == x) // On the first pass, sum == x
        printf("%d", sum);
    else
        printf(",%d", sum);
}
```

Of course, this could break if you have negative values. In that case, keeping a counter or bool would be better.

Comment: what if I enter `0` several times ?

Comment: Then use a boolean or an index counter. This would be the more robust way regardless. Also, if it's `0` then the loop would break and you wouldn't print it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

print comma only after the first iteration (use a custom flag) , print result no matter what:

```
int first_iteration = 1;

...

if (!first_iteration)
{
   printf(",");
}
sum += x;
first_iteration = 0;
printf("%d", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always a clumsy but tried-and-true method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x, sum;
    sum = 0;
    comma = 0;
    while(x)
    {
        scanf("%d", &x);
        sum += x;
        if(x != 0)
        {
            if (comma != 0)
            {
                printf(",");
            }
            printf("%d", sum);
            comma = 1;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```